# Notify the server when the user changes the value of any component in the form

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I have a form made of Apache Trinidad components.

I need to inform to the server when any of the components of the form (inputtext, selectBooleanCheckbox, etc) has changed its value/state.

I was expecting a kind of listener in the form component but it appears to not exist.

Must I add a changeValueListener to each component of the form or is there another less verbose method?

Answer (score 0):

Within the component you can include `<f:ajax execute="myInput" event="change" />`